# How to avoid passing configuration across functions?

Tags: functional-programming

I am writing module that other people can use in their code. It's a calendar.
I want to allow users to set locale parameter so that they have month names and other data in language of their choice.

I could create Calendar class that accepts `locale`, `startOfWeekDay` as arguments.
Methods of that class will those properties so there is no need to pass them to each method.

```js
export class Calendar {
    static WEEKDAYS = {sunday: 0, ...};

    constructor(year, month, options = {locale: 'en-US', startOfWeekDay: Calendar.WEEKDAYS.sunday}) {
        this.locale = options.locale;
        this.startOfWeekDay = options.startOfWeekDay;
        this.calendar = this.getCalendar(year, month);
    }

    /**
     * returns True or False whether given day is first day of week
     */
    isFirstDayOfWeek(day) {
        // depends on this.startOfWeekDay
    }

    /**
     * returns True or False whether given day is last day of week
     */
    isLastDayOfWeek(day) {
        // depends on this.startOfWeekDay
    }

    /**
     * returns list of objects representing a calendar
     * [ {day: 1, month: 1, year: 2019, weekDayName: 'Sunday' }, ... ]
     */
    getCalendar(year, month) {
        // depends on this.locale to return correct weekDayName
    }

    /**
     * returns list of week day names: ['Sunday', 'Monday', ... ];
     */
    getWeekDays() {
        // depends on this.locale & this.startOfWeekDay
    }
}
```

If I would want to rewrite it using more functional approach, what first comes to mind is to ask user to pass locale to each function that depends on it:

```js
const WEEKDAYS = {sunday: 0, ...};
export function isFirstDayOfWeek(startOfWeekDay, day) {}
export function isLastDayOfWeek(startOfWeekDay, day) {}
export function getCalendar(year, month, options = {locale: 'en-US'}) {}
export function getWeekDays(options = {locale: 'en-US', startOfWeekDay: WEEKDAYS.sunday}) {}
```

What functional programming concepts would you use?

Comment: If your question is "How do you write functions in a referentially-transparent way without passing locale and other required data," the answer is "you can't."

Comment: Too busy to write a full-fledged answer at the moment. The standard solution to ambient configuration data is the Reader Monad.

Comment: *"I want to use a functional style but don't want to pass configuration as a parameter, how else do I pass configuration?"* - the question is, why would you wish to? The whole *point* of functional programming is to cause all variation in execution to occur only as the consequence of explicit parameters provided.

Comment: I would like to reduce repetition (e.g passing locale as a parameter to multiple functions) both for the consumer of the module and in the code of the module itself.
Is it considered a normal practice to pass config parameters explicitly to keep functions pure?